# Astar Pathfinding Project setting z position of AI agent to incorrect values in 2D project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game in Unity and am using the [A* Pathfinding Package from Aron Granberg](https://arongranberg.com/astar/).

Everything appears to be working fine.  AIPaths are being generated and AI Agents are navigating from point to point and avoiding obstacles as expected.  It's fine *except for one thing*.

The `position.z` of the AI Agent is incorrect.

The spawn origin of the AI Agent has a z of 0, and the target point has a z of 0, yet the AI Agent's z fluctuates between -9 and -1 as it traverses the path.  The path itself appears to have a z position of 0 at each waypoint.

I haven't modified the code in the package at all and just followed the documentation when setting it up for 2D.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

***NOTE: I haven't included a screenshot of it, but the prefab that is being spawned in as the AI Agent has a transform position of (0,0,0).***

**The A-star pathfinder object:**

[image: Pathfinder and grid graph set up]

**The AI Agent object (note that the Z pos is not 0):**
[image]

**The spawn point object that sets the spawn for the AI agent:**
[image]

**The destination target object that the AI Agent is heading to:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem.

The fix was to add a Rigidbody2D to my AI Agent and set the gravity scale to 0.

Even though my game doesn't use Unity's physics system for movement and the Astar package can move AI agents by transform, for some reason it requires a Rigidbody to keep the Z position at 0.

I'm still not really sure why this solves the problem because, when I was debugging the third-party Astar code, it always returned nextPosition values with a Z position of 0 yet the actual position that the AI Agent was updated to had varying Z positions...

If you have more info, leave a comment and I'll add it to the answer.